# Is there a way to programatically update DNS records?

Tags: domain-name-system

Is there a standard way to programatically update DNS records? Services like Route 53 do offer programmatic access, but is that possible in a generic way using some standard protocol? Or it depends on the registrar (e.g. I read that GoDaddy don't allow programmatic access)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a standardized interface.  RFC 2136 describes it.  The `nsupdate` program that comes with BIND implements it.  As far as I know most DNS servers support it.  You'll have to shop around carefully though unless you're running your own DNS servers, as a lot of providers don't enable it.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS#Standards-based_dynamic_DNS_update
http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/xfer.html#allow-update

Comment: Good answer. I am amazed at how many seasoned admins will state as fact that there is no api for BIND (as demonstrated by the other answers) when ddns provides exactly that. There are even perl/python modules that can provide a more programmatic interface.

Comment: Some examples of libraries like what Andy mentioned: [dnspython](http://www.dnspython.org/), [Net::DNS (perl)](http://www.net-dns.org/), [ldns (C)](http://www.nlnetlabs.nl/projects/ldns/), [dnsjava](http://www.dnsjava.org/)

Comment: @Andy That said, enabling DDNS in BIND isn't without its challenges. If you enable it, it will destroy all your comments and record ordering. It will also require that all involved adopt to using the `freeze`+`thaw` rndc workflow. It's best to isolate DDNS updates to their own subdomain where possible.

Answer (score 3):

You could easily run your own DNS system. Bind9's text file databases can be easy manipulated.

Comment: This works. I've been running a system configured this way for over a decade. It's simple and effective.

Answer (score 1):

jeffsnider's answer is correct. However, be aware you can also do the 'hidden master' trick. Here your primaries slave (i.e. AXFR) from a 'hidden master'. That hidden master need only support AXFR. An easy way to achieve this is to run the nameserver of your choice and generate text files for it in perl or whatever. You need not worry about performance or reloading it as it won't be receiving any real queries. It can be behind a firewall if necessary.